# how to integrate charCount into for-loop

Tags: java

so my task is to count every f within the given String by using a for loop and then output the sum. Here is my try but I don't know what this error code means. [image]

```
 // e)
    String string = "Schiffe für den Fischfang.";
    int result4 = 0;

    for (int stelle = 1; stelle <= string.length(); stelle++) {
        if (string.charAt(stelle) == 102) {
            result4++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is zero indexed. So start at 0 and stop `< string.length()` not equal to it. That's what's causing your IndexOutOfBoundsException. A 26 character string can only be indexed from 0 to 25.

If you're requirement is for any kind of f you'll need to also test an ascii value of 70 to count the capital F as well. Either that or use `toLowerCase()` before looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert your string to character array and iterate through it. Like following,

```
String string = "Schiffe für den Fischfang.";
int result4 = 0;
for (char c: string.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == 102) {
        result4++;
    }
}
```

#### Your solutions

```
String string = "Schiffe für den Fischfang.";
int result4 = 0;
for (int stelle = 1; stelle < string.length(); stelle++) {
    if (string.charAt(stelle) == 102) {
        result4++;
    }
}
```